# Function in a react component

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to learn React so forgive me if this question belies some ignorance...but I'll try to keep things simple.

I have a component in my react app called "Starset0"

This is it:

```
 import React from "react";

 const Starset0 = props => (
  <div id = "rating0">
   <img class = "star" id = "1" src = {require('./empty-star.png')} />
   <img class = "star" id = "2" src = {require('./empty-star.png')} />
   <img class = "star" id = "3" src = {require('./empty-star.png')} />
   <img class = "star" id = "4" src = {require('./empty-star.png')}/>
   <img class = "star" id = "5" src = {require('./empty-star.png')}/>
  </div>


 );

 export default Starset0;
```

Although what I'm trying to do is more complicated,

let's start simple: How would I write a function that would cause the src of any image (star) clicked to change to

```
{require('./full-star.png')}
```

?

Comment: You shouldn't have a Sterset0 component but rather a generic Starset component that receives the rating as a prop and renders the starts dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Make each star it's own component. Something like:

```
class Star extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src={this.state.full ? fullStar : emptyStar}
        onClick={this.toggleFull}
      />
    );
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { full: false };

    this.toggleFull = this.toggleFull.bind(this);
  }

  toggleFull() {
    this.setState({ full: !this.state.full });
  }
}
```

You probably want to pass Starset with a prop saying how many full/empty stars and then you can render the stars dynamically. But that's for another question :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should import/require your methods at the top of the file and **not inside a method/Component**. The reason is, Component code will be transpiled to native JavaScript code by webpack or any other bundler you use.
2. Load both the images in the beginning and use an onClick listener to change the src.

So the answer to you question is,

```
import React from "react";
// require the image src below
const fullStarSrc =
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0VTgrxQ2qHQsg64mHBLUHg7Lvd5JwD_sgRPfTxewBOrWhnvjqPQ";
const halfStarSrc =
  "https://visualpharm.com/assets/247/Star%20Half-595b40b85ba036ed117dab5e.svg";

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeSrc = this.changeSrc.bind(this);
  }

  changeSrc(e) {
    // This is example code and the condition to check might not be right
    // but this.elem.offsetTop will give you the element's current top position
    if (e.target && e.target.src) {
      e.target.src = fullStarSrc;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="rating0">
        <img
          width="100px"
          height="100px"
          src={halfStarSrc}
          onClick={e => this.changeSrc(e)}
        />
        <img
          width="100px"
          height="100px"
          src={halfStarSrc}
          onClick={e => this.changeSrc(e)}
        />
        <img
          width="100px"
          height="100px"
          src={halfStarSrc}
          onClick={e => this.changeSrc(e)}
        />
        <img
          width="100px"
          height="100px"
          src={halfStarSrc}
          onClick={e => this.changeSrc(e)}
        />
        <img
          width="100px"
          height="100px"
          src={halfStarSrc}
          onClick={e => this.changeSrc(e)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

You'll find the working example here - [Half Star to Full Star](https://codesandbox.io/s/m35jr2lylp)